# Mount SMB share (CIFS) to container using secured credentials or token

Tags: network-shares, smb, cifs, docker-for-windows, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose setup that runs my Linux development environment on Windows. A number of these containers need to mount smb drives using LDAP credentials. The way this woks now is by adding a command like this to the container entrypoint:

```
mount -t cifs -o username=$USERNAME,password=$PASSWORD \\\\myshare.domain.com\\path_to_shared\\directory /mnt/z
```

The environment variables `$USERNAME` and `$PASSWORD` are **saved in plain text** in a file named `auth.env`. This is in my Windows home directory, which docker-compose adds to the container as an environment file.

I can't have a prompt for every time a container starts up, because as a process of my workflow, they are constantly being restarted.

My understanding is that the way cifs authenticates is by generating token, which is then used throughout the session. I wonder if I can retrieve this token, save it in memory (or even to disk if need be), then use it to mount these drives.

Answer (score 2):

> My understanding is that the way cifs authenticates is by generating token, which is then used throughout the session.

SMB (and the obsolete CIFS) mainly use NTLMv2 authentication, which is a form of challenge-response protocol. This means that the response is deliberately made dynamic – every time you connect you get a new challenge and must send a new response, rather than something you (or an attacker) could replay over and over.

The only static step in this protocol is the "NTLM hash" (an MD4 hash of your password). Some SMB clients might allow using it instead of a password; unfortunately, it doesn't really help much because *any* service accepting this account via NTLM will involve the same hash – if you use the same password on five fileservers and two RDP servers, knowing the NTLM hash allows logging in to all of them. In other words, the hash is password-equivalent.

SMB also supports Kerberos if your fileserver is connected to Active Directory, but that is in more or less the same situation. Although the Kerberos ticket that the SMB presents to servers *is* bound to that server only, it is also designed to expire quickly – 10 hours is typical (though renewing it for up to 7 days may be possible). To get a new ticket, you still need access to the account's primary credentials (either the password itself or its hash/keytab).

So the short-term answer is to use Kerberos: get a TGT using `kinit`, copy your entire krb5cc file to the container, it's valid for 10 hours and will have expired the next day.

The long-term answer is to make Docker use a *separate account* that has only the access it needs. Then storing it on disk is less of a problem because stealing it only gives access to what the container has mounted anyway.